# Mysql query execution plan has caching?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, sql-execution-plan

I've looked everywhere for my issue but found no definite answer.
Database: MySQL
Given three numerical fields a, b, c and One datetime filed d, all indexed separately
The involved table holds 10 mil. records.

Two numbers n,m

I have a basic query:

```
select * where (a=n or b=n) and c IN(m) Order by d DESC
```

(n can be any number, m can be any number through 1-9)
I also have a separate index on each one of them. I've tried indexes on ac and bc but with no success.

On my development environment I always get an index merge which makes the query fast even though it makes a filesort for some reason that I dont' really care about.

But on production(different sever-same schema/data) that doesn't happen no matter what I do.

My workaround to this weird issue was turning the query into the following statement:

From:

```
select * where (a=n or b=n) and c IN(m) ORDER BY d desc
```

To:

```
select * where (a=n or b=n) and c IN(m,'m') ORDER BY d desc
```

And that resulted in an merge index query on the production environment as well
which basically for me means that there's an execution plan cache somewhere and I can't figure out for the life of me where to clear that cache (if indeed there is one)

I need to know how can I tell the production environment to properly use that index in the first statement.

As a note ... for some reason Explain query tells me that d is the index used on production when explaining the query.

Comment: _“m can be any number through 1-9”_ – so it is a single number, not a list of numbers? If the former – then why are you using IN?

Comment: No idea about MySQL but other DBMS use statistics to build execution plans. If your systems don't have identical data, identical specs and identical load you'll often get different plans.

Comment: @CBroe Same thing happens even if I change it to c=m. I have other queries as well that use multiple values for m and that's why I use IN. So whether it's c=m or c IN(m) the same outcome happens.

Comment: Well then I’d suggest you compare the MySQL server settings between your development and production environment. Easily possible that different settings for caches, RAM etc. result in those difference you’re seeing.

Comment: Note: (in July 2019) MySQL does NOT have an execution plan cache: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42808

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know how can I tell the production environment to properly use that index in the first statement.

Use the "force index" syntax.

If you paste CREATE TABLE & EXPLAIN output for the tables & queries involved (resp.) on dev & production we can narrow it down to a just a couple things. Might also help to know the RAM available on each machine.

ps:

> On my development environment I always get an index merge which makes the query fast even though it makes a filesort for some reason that I dont' really care about.

sorting by d which isn't in your index